# generating random numbers without duplicates in java

Tags: java

So I am generating random coordinates on a given grid that contains x number of rows and y number of columns. Let's say I want to generate 25 random numbers on a 8 by 6 grid.(8 columns, 6 rows)
I wrote piece of code like this and it is only partially working because this code does not excludes duplicates:

```
    int intputRows =6;
    int inputColumns=8;
    Random randomNumGenerator = new Random();
        for(int i=0;i<25;i++){
            int randomRows = randomNumGenerator.nextInt(inputRows);
            int randomColumns = randomNumGenerator.nextInt(inputColumns);
        }
```

My question is, how do I avoid to generate duplicate numbers? I understand there are ways like put those in a `List` structure and shuffle, but could I done it with `Random` generator?

Comment: Please search before psoting.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have taken a closer look at the question you marked as duplicate, in fact I do not think they are the same. The answer only provides a way to deal with one random numbers, which is fine when using `Set`, my question needs to handle two random numbers, in this case it does not work with a `Set`, please consider reopen the question.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `Set`:

```
int intputRows =6;
int inputColumns=8;
HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
Random randomNumGenerator = new Random();
int temp;
    for(int i=0;i<25;i++){
        temp = randomNumGenerator.nextInt(inputRows);
        if(set.add(temp))
            int randomRows = temp;
        temp = randomNumGenerator.nextInt(inputRows);
        if(set.add(temp))
            int randomColumns = temp;
    }
```

You still have to implement an `else`, in case it already exists, but I just gave you the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Simple add the numbers to a `Set`, for example a `HashSet`, which cannot contain duplicate values, until your Set hat the desired length.

```
Set<Integer> randomNumbers = new HashSet<Integer>();
while(randomNumbers.size() < 25) {
    randomNumbers.add( randomNumGenerator.nextInt(inputRows) );
}
```

Of course some checks would be nice to test that there is a chance that the code will finish, etc.